# DYMO SDK Print image

Tags: image, dymo

This question is about DYMO SDK. Is there any possibility to print image (from PDF)  to the label along with some text? Does anyone have good example?

Comment: The SDK supports many lanuages. Which one are you looking for? You may find some basics for a simple JS approach here: https://dr-nielsen.com/php/print-from-browser-directly-to-dymo-labelwriter